# Trying to use 'AntColony' class from 'pyaco' library in Python, getting 'ModuleNotFoundError' - how to solve?

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

Problem with connecting the pyaco library

I downloaded the library like this `pip install pyaco`.
Try to import class AntColony `from pyaco import AntColony`.
I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaco'`.
Tried installing an older version didn't help.
Code example

```
from pyaco import AntColony
import numpy as np

distance_matrix = np.array([[0, 2, 9, 10],
                            [1, 0, 6, 4],
                            [15, 7, 0, 8],
                            [6, 3, 12, 0]])

ant_colony = AntColony(distance_matrix, num_ants=20, num_iterations=1000, alpha=1.0, beta=3.0, evaporation_rate=0.5, Q=100)

best_path, best_distance = ant_colony.solve()

print("Best path:", best_path)
print("Best distance:", best_distance)
```

Comment: The actual python module name is `PyACO`, not `pyaco`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Main page helped me.  https://github.com/ganyariya/PyACO/blob/master/README.md